# Back stack is getting cleared when we navigate between activities via deeplink URI

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, android-deep-link

I have an ActivityA and an ActivityB (in a library module). I navigate from ActivityA to ActivityB via startActivity().

Inside ActivityB I have a NavHost and a Composable which is resolving a deeplink.

When I press back, I have the ActivityA in the back stack but when I launch the ActivityB via a deep link URI, ActivityA in the backstack seems to have
destroyed(printed onDestroy to confirm it) since the back stack is empty when I press back from ActivityB, the application closes.

Both Activity A & B has the launch mode as SingleTask. Any help in understanding why ActivityA is getting destroyed is deeply appreciated.

```
Flow 1 

    startActivity(Intent
(this,ActivityB::class.java))


            startActivity()             backpress()
ActivityA ------------------> ActivityB -----------> ActivityA  


Flow 2

val intent = Intent()
intent.data = "activityB://test"
startActivity(intent)

           via URI (deeplink)              backpress()
ActivityA --------------------> ActivityB -------------> Closes application 
        |
        |
        |
        ------>ActivityA
                destroyed
```

Comment: Hello @Vikram Ragu, did you found any solution for this. I too have same issue.

Comment: Hi @Raj, I couldn't find a solution yet. Btw, is your destination activity a compose screen?

Comment: yes, I have Activity A -> DeeplinkActivity with In-App Link -> Activity B. by the time Activity B is started, Activity A & Deeplink activities are destroyed. 
My requirement is like when Activity B is opened, Activity A also should be there in stack, and that(Activity A) should appear on Back press from Activity B

Comment: @Raj, I'm unable to find a concrete solution :(